# MapKit Showing current location with SwiftUI 2 (not using UIRepresentable)

Tags: swiftui, mapkit

Trying to get the map to center on the current location.  It is showing "Updated Location" over and over again, it then doesn't change the map the current location.  If you scroll to your current location, it shows the blue dot.

```
struct Home:View {

   @State var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.086, longitude: 80.2769), latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)
   @State var trackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow
   @State var manager = CLLocationManager()
   @StateObject var managerDelegate = LocationDelegate()

   var body:some View {
       VStack {
           Map(coordinateRegion: $region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $trackingMode)
       }
       .onAppear {
          manager.delegate = managerDelegate
       }
   }
}


class LocationDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
       if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
           print("Authorized...")
           manager.startUpdatingLocation()
       } else {
           print("Not Authorized...")
           manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       }
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       print("Updated Location")
   }
 }
```

Comment: `CLLocationManager` and the map view are two different animals.

Comment: I edited the code to get rid of CLLocationManager (as it wasn't needed).  With the code above, it still does the same thing.   It will put a blue dot at my current location, but the map doesn't go to that dot automatically, it says at the lat / long that was set in the region.  How do I get this to automatically show the current location?  (info.plist has the proper entries)

Comment: Que!?  How are you going to get the current location without using `CLLocationManager`?

Comment: Well then how do you get CLLocationManager to work with Map?  That's the original question that you said were "two different animals"

Comment: Originally, you did not make any connection between the two.  You should have used a state value to pass data from one to the other.

Comment: Code is back to its original form with the CLLocationManager.  Can you see where the missing link is between the Map and the Manager?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the answer.

```
struct Home:View {

   @State var trackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow
   @State var manager = CLLocationManager()
   @StateObject var managerDelegate = LocationDelegate()

   var body:some View {
       VStack {
           Map(coordinateRegion: $managerDelegate.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $trackingMode)
       }
       .onAppear {
           manager.delegate = managerDelegate
       }
   }
}

class LocationDelegate: NSObject, ObservableObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate         {

   @Published var  region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 13.086, longitude: 80.2769), latitudinalMeters: 10000, longitudinalMeters: 10000)

   func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
       if manager.authorizationStatus == .authorizedWhenInUse {
           print("Authorized...")
           manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
           manager.startUpdatingLocation()
       } else {
           print("Not Authorized...")
           manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
       }
   }

   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
       print("Updated Location")
       region.center.latitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.latitude)!
       region.center.longitude = (manager.location?.coordinate.longitude)!
   }
}
```